# How to delete columns from a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, delete-row

I have a list of more than 80 csv files, all with the same row headings and number of columns. This is the head of one of my csv files within the list:

```
         Date Tx2m Tn2m   Pr
1    1/1/1988   NA   NA  0.0
2    1/2/1988   NA   NA  0.0
3    1/3/1988   NA   NA  0.0
4    1/4/1988   NA   NA  0.0
5    1/5/1988   NA   NA  0.0
```

I want to delete both the "Tx2m" and Tn2m" columns which in all of my files have Null values.

I tried running this code:

```
lapply(myList, function(x) { x["Tx2m"] <- NULL; x })
```

But I get the following error message: Error in x["Tx2m"] <- NULL : replacement has length zero.

How can I delete these columns and save them again as CSV files within my working directory?

Comment: Use `x[,"Tx2m"] <- NULL` or `x[["Tx2m"]] <- NULL` because `x` is a data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to do this automatically by finding at least one non-NA element in a column and `Filter` only those columns as `list` elements could potentially differ in the NA contents

```
myList <- lapply(myList, function(x) Filter(function(u) any(!is.na(u)) u))
```

---

Or another option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
myList <- map(myList, ~ .x %>%
          select(where(~ any(!is.na(.)))))
```

Comment: after I select those with NA values can I delete those columns so my csv files will only contain my wanted columns?